# What mistake am I making here?

Tags: sql, hive

I am running below queries on hive, 1 is running fine but other one fails, could you please me with why 2nd one is failing.
Basically i am doing a word query in hive.

Query #1 (doesn't work)

```sql
select 
    word, count(1) 
from 
    (select 
         explode(split(s,' ')) AS word 
     from 
         lines) 
group by 
    word
```

Query #2: (works fine)

```sql
SELECT 
    word, count(1) 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         explode(split(s, ' ')) AS word 
     FROM 
         lines) q
GROUP BY 
    word
```

Answer (score 0):

The first query is missing a sub-query name. The second one has it (as `q`).

```
SELECT ... FROM (subquery) name ...
```

See [the language manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+subqueries) for more information.